# how to include zend library while uploading?

Tags: uploading

I have completed my project in zend framework for the first time. But I don't know how to include zend library in webhost. So, I uploaded(uploading) zend library about 24MB in my library folder. Can this be done without it? Or if there is any better solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hosts have the Zend Framework installed on the server as a PHP extension. But most likely you will need to upload the framework yourself. I'm not too familiar with Zend or its structure but it may be possible to only upload the libraries that you are using in your application and skip the ones you are not using to save time/space.